# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x→4}x^{1/2}=2$ by using epsilon-delta

Tags: limits, analysis, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $\lim\limits_{x→4} x^{1/2}=2$  given $ε=1$ by using epsilon-delta.

I know that given $ε>0$, $∃ δ>0$ such that if $0<|x−4|<δ$, then $|x^{1/2}-2|<ε$. The thing is I am stuck on how to expand the previous expression to find $δ$.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Guide:

$$\left|\sqrt{x} - 2 \right|=\left|\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x}+2} \right| $$

- Find a lower bound for $\sqrt{x}+2$, you can impose conditions such as $\delta$ can't be bigger than $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can work the problem like this:
$$|x^{1/2}-2| < |x^{1/2}+2||x^{1/2}-2| = |x-4|$$
So if you take $\delta = \epsilon$, we are done.

Comment: Probably better to write it as $\delta = \epsilon$ for better clarity: while the original is logically equivalent, it makes it seem like you are choosing $\epsilon$ rather than the $\delta$, which may steer someone in the wrong direction, especially if they are coming from a computing background.

Comment: Ok, I changed it.